# Using DomPDF in Cakephp Delivers an error Cannot redeclare class Dompdf\View\PdfView

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, dompdf

I have a problem printing a PDF using CakePHP and DomPDF as soon I want to fetch some data from the Database before printing the pdf. Without fetching the Data, it works like a charme. My function is the following:

```
public function tourpdf($tourid = null){

  $contain = ['Deliveries','Deliveries.Articletransactions','Deliveries.Orders','Deliveries.Orders.Customers',
            'Deliveries.Articletransactions.Orderarticles','Deliveries.Articletransactions.Orderarticles.Articles'];

  $tour = $this->Tours->get($tourid)
            ->contain($contain);

  $this->viewBuilder()
    ->className('Dompdf.Pdf')
    ->layout('Dompdf.default')
    ->options(['config' => [
        'filename' => $filename,
        'render' => 'browser',
        'size' => 'A4',
        'orientation' => 'landscape'
    ]]);

  $this->set('Test', 'Hallo');
  $this->set('Tour',$tour);
}
```

As soon as I set the Data from the last line, that I fetched above, I get the error Message "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Dompdf\View\PdfView in .../src/View/PdfView.php on line 66".

However commenting the last line out, the first set with Test is working and the PDF is generated. How can I set data retrieving from a query to the pdf file?

Comment: `Dompdf.Pdf`/`Dompdf.default`? What is that? Surely it's not part of the Dompdf library. Also whenever receiving errors, please always post **the _complete_ error**, that is, **including the _full_ stacktrace** (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion), and show the related code that triggers the error. Also please always mention the _exact_ versions of the software involved (CakePHP, Dompdf, ...) - thanks.

Comment: I followed the instrunctions on "https://github.com/DaoAndCo/cakephp-dompdf". I am using Cakephp 3 and the newest version of the plugin. 

The error is the full Error Log. There are no more errors.

`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Dompdf\View\PdfView in .../src/View/PdfView.php on line 66`

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error, but with Zend Framework 2. All of a sudden DOMPDF would give an error "Cannot redeclare  (previously declared in ...)".

I had PHP functions in some templates and when I removed them I was getting another error "No block-level parent found.  Not good.". I noticed this started happening when I upgraded libxml2 from 2.9.4 to 2.9.5 or later.

The solution to both of the problems was to instantiate DOMPDF class like this:

```
use Dompdf\Options;
$options = new Options();
$options->set('enable_html5_parser', true);
$dompdf = new Dompdf($options);
```

With enable_html5_parser all the problems went away. [Here is some more information on this issue](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1494).

Answer (score 0):

Amazing!

Had this issue on Mac 10.12.6
PHP Version 5.6.30
libxml Version 2.9.4

Using the regex to remove whitespace between the tags fixed the issue.

```
$html = preg_replace('/>\s+</', '><', $html);
```